# Bigquery SQL Long Text Split with number

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a data containing a long string that looks like this

```
id | desc |
1 | "1. xxxxxx 2. yyyyyyyy 3. zzzzzzz"
2 | "1. xxxx 2. yyyy
3 | "1. XXX
```

I want to split it based on number to become row

```
id | desc
1 | 1. xxx
1 | 2. yyyy
1 | 3. zzz
2 | 1. xxx
2 | 2. yyyy
```

Is there any way i can do this in bigquery SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select id, `desc`
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest(regexp_extract_all(`desc`, r'(\d+. \w+)')) `desc`
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - as in below example

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1 id, "1. xxxxxx 2. yyyyyyyy 3. zzzzzzz" `desc`union all
  select 2, "1. xxxx 2. yyyy" union all
  select 3, "1. XXX" 
)
select id, `desc`
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest(regexp_extract_all(`desc`, r'(\d+. \w+)')) `desc`
```

output is

[image]